# Authentication using Spring Security and JBoss 7.2

Tags: spring, spring-mvc, jboss, spring-security

I am looking for a way to authenticate my users against Active Directory in a Spring Security web application, running on JBoss 7.2.

Following [that link](http://www.mkyong.com/spring-security/get-current-logged-in-username-in-spring-security/), I always get "anonymousUser", but would like to see my own username instead. It seems that Spring Security uses anonymous authentication when the primary authentication strategy does not work.

Here is my setup:

- Spring 4.0.6
- Spring Security 3.2.4

**SecurityConfig.java**

```
@Configuration
@EnableWebMvcSecurity
public class SecurityConfig extends WebSecurityConfigurerAdapter {

    @Autowired
    public void registerGlobalAuthentication(AuthenticationManagerBuilder auth) throws Exception {

        DefaultSpringSecurityContextSource context = new DefaultSpringSecurityContextSource("ldap://my_ldap_server:389");
        context.setUserDn("MY_SERVICE_ACCOUNT_DISTINGUISHED_NAME");
        context.setPassword("MY_SERVICE_ACCOUNT_PASSWORD");
        context.afterPropertiesSet();

        auth
            .ldapAuthentication()
            .contextSource(context)
            .userDnPatterns("(sAMAccountName={0})")
            .rolePrefix("");
    }

    @Override
    protected void configure(HttpSecurity http) throws Exception {

        /*
        http
            .authorizeRequests()
            .anyRequest().authenticated();
        */
    }
}
```

If I uncomment the configure(HttpSecurity http) method body, I got the 403 Access Denied page, which means (I guess) I am not authenticated.

**LoginController.java**

```
@Controller
public class LoginController {

        @RequestMapping(value = "/login", method = RequestMethod.GET)
        public String login() {

            Authentication auth = SecurityContextHolder.getContext().getAuthentication();
            String strRemoteUser = auth.getName();

            System.out.println("[SPRING4BASE] Welcome " + strRemoteUser);

            return "welcome";
        }
}
```

**jboss-web.xml**

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>

<!DOCTYPE policy PUBLIC 
    "-//JBoss//DTD JBOSS Security Config 3.0//EN" 
    "http://www.jboss.org/j2ee/dtd/security_config.dtd">

<jboss-web>
    <security-domain>java:/jaas/other</security-domain>
</jboss-web>
```

**JBoss security domain definition (standalone.xml):**

```
<subsystem xmlns="urn:jboss:domain:security:1.2">
    <security-domains>
        <security-domain name="other" cache-type="default">
            <authentication>
                <login-module code="org.jboss.security.auth.spi.LdapExtLoginModule" flag="required">
                    <module-option name="java.naming.provider.url" value="ldap://my_ldap_server:389"/>
                    <module-option name="java.naming.security.authentication" value="simple"/>
                    <module-option name="java.naming.referral" value="follow"/>
                    <module-option name="bindDN" value="MY_SERVICE_ACCOUNT_DISTINGUISHED_NAME"/>
                    <module-option name="bindCredential" value="MY_SERVICE_ACCOUNT_PASSWORD"/>
                    <module-option name="baseCtxDN" value="MY_BASE_LDAP_CONTEXT"/>
                    <module-option name="baseFilter" value="(sAMAccountName={0})"/>
                    <module-option name="rolesCtxDN" value="MY_BASE_LDAP_CONTEXT"/>
                    <module-option name="roleFilter" value="(member={1})"/>
                    <module-option name="roleAttributeID" value="CN"/>
                    <module-option name="searchScope" value="SUBTREE_SCOPE"/>
                    <module-option name="allowEmptyPasswords" value="false"/>
                </login-module>
            </authentication>
        </security-domain>
    </security-domains>
</subsystem>
```

Finally, my requirement is that if the current user has an active session on my organization's network, he must have access to the application. Then, the application security strategy handles the authorization.

Your help is much appreciated.

Comment: Are the end users signed in to your enterprise network on windows or unix?

Comment: @6ton : On Windows. I know in the past (JBoss 4.2.3), we were using JCIFS for injecting the current user information into the request object. But now, our organization is leaning towards Kerberos (PicketLink), so that may be my problem. A Kerberos configuration may be required in my case.

Comment: I haven't really worked on this but this seems relevant.: http://thekspace.com/home/component/content/article/54-kerberos-and-spnego.html